# Create Folder on Users' Mailboxes

Tags: powershell

I would like to create a remote folder inside Inbox with this command wit o365 exchange when execute the following command:

```
New-MailboxFolder -Parent 'username@domain.com:\Inbox\Folder1' -Name 'Folder1.1'
```

However, this command cannot be used to create folders on other user’s mailbox.
The error is:

> The specified mailbox “username@domain.com” doesn’t exist

What's the exactly problem with this command? Anybody know any Workaround? Thanks!

Comment: Going by the error I can only assume you have yet to create the mailbox account?

Answer (score 2):

The cmdlet you're trying to use is not supposed to work for mailboxes other than your own (even if you have proper rights). From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/new-mailboxfolder?view=exchange-ps):

> Use the New-MailboxFolder cmdlet to create folders in your own mailbox. **Administrators can't use this cmdlet to create folders in other mailboxes** (the cmdlet is available only from the MyBaseOptions user role).

Some possible workarounds are:

1. Use [Create MailFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-mailfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) from Graph API
2. Use MFCMAPI (probably not trivial to be automated)

More detailed description can be found [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/69d4d386-03c3-4c82-a8db-cb7819f63016/encounter-error-with-command-newmailboxfolder-the-specified-mailbox-doesnt-exist?forum=exchangesvrgeneral).